# Which wiki software does CentOS.org use?

Tags: centos, software-rec, wiki

If you goto CentOS.org and hit up the wiki, I am trying to figure out which wiki software it is. Usually I can scroll to the bottom and get the wiki software name and version from the footer.

Answer (score 4):

It looks like [MoinMoin](http://moinmo.in/), judging by the format of the search URL and its results: http://wiki.centos.org/CategoryHomepage?action=fullsearch&context=180&value=moin&titlesearch=Titles

This is confirmed by the presence of this page: http://wiki.centos.org/AboutMoinWiki